# Magento 2 Multistore how to handle logout on same browser

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, multistore, logout

I'm a Magento 2 newbie. In my site we have 2 store- **default** and **wholesale**.

Account Login to default store will be like this - http://example.com/customer/account/login/ and for wholsesale store http://example.com/wholesale/customer/account/login

When I try to login to two store using different account from same browser it will work, but when I try to logout from one store it logging me out from another store also. How I can prevent this. I need to keep logging me in another(wholesale) store even if I logged out from default store.

I need this to work on same browser.

I created a module and tried to override logout action.

This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace Customvendor\Custommodule\Controller\Customer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Logout extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        //$this->session = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->redirect = $context->getRedirect();
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;

    }
    public function execute() {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $customerId = $this->customerSession->getId();
        if($customerId) {
            //echo $customerId;exit;
            $this->customerSession->logout()
                 ->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl())
                 ->setLastCustomerId($customerId);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Logout successfully'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login/');  
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Customer is not logged in'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login/');
        }

    }
}
```

Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

what you can do, you need to create a new extension and override the logout controller and event. There before logging out, you need to fetch the website ID, and use the logout event for that website only just like Magento does in case of "Per website" account sharing option and prevent magento logout event, which will be global in your case.

Comment: I've added my code in question. How can I add websiteID basis condition?

Comment: It is there in default Magento when per website is enabled. Magento generate cache based on that. Give me some time to find out.